Spring boot, dockerized and deployed on google cloud vm/kubernetes: servlet hangs inexplicably
I have a spring boot application with tomcat that receives files from the user and uploads them to google cloud storage, then save the public url to a postgresql database.
It works normally when run in IDE or dockerized and run locally. However, when I deploy it to google cloud vm or google cloud kubernetes, it randomly stops receiving requests after several uploads (about 60-120 files). Turning on debug logging, I see this log:
2024-11-26 14:55:17 [http-nio-8282-Poller] DEBUG o.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - timeout completed: keys processed=1; now=1732607717764; nextExpiration=1732607717763; keyCount=1; hasEvents=false; eval=false

with keys processed being the number of successful requests, and keyCount being the number of requests sent to the application after it started stopping receving requests. I have an interceptor to log incoming requests, and the request caught by the above line doesn't reach it.
At all logging levels, no errors are ever thrown, not even out of memory, no threads locked or dead, and the application seems to hang indefinitely regardless of the timeouts I set. What can I do to find the source of this problem?

I'm leaning towards a distributed system setup issue. Are requests not received at all, or is it only the file upload requests that start failing (ruling out network/LB). Can you explain more about your setup in Kubernetes? Any load balancers involved?
